# Suggested edits count is broken, shows -1

Tags: bug

[image]

To replicate:

- Get one or two suggested edits.
- Load the suggested edits page.
- Approve the edits really really quickly.
- Watch.

Comment: I haven't seen it, but +1 sheerly for the specific 'to replicate' directions

Comment: Don't approve edits quickly ,:p ,read it before approve

Comment: @abcd Oh I do. It's just that the diff is pretty easy to read after you've see almost 1K edits, and read countless other diffs. ;P

Comment: I found a related question on Meta.SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133602/should-it-be-possible-to-have-a-negative-number-of-suggested-edits-in-the-queue